# Displaying foreign key data in Windows Application GridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have two Tables

```
'Item Catagory' with fields

CatagoryId
```

and

```
CatagoryName
```

and `Items`

with fields

```
ItemId
```

and

```
CatagoryId
```

Now on `Item Form` I want to Display `Item` Data in A `DataGridView`

I want to Display `CatogoryName` From `ItemCatogory`Table in a GridView Columm

Currently I am not able to do that, Can Any One Help me in this Regard ???

Comment: Theres a lot of way. which one do you want Dataset, Linq, entityframework, SqlCommand?

Answer (score 1):

Your Query to bind with gridview should be like this.

```
SELECT Items.ItemId, ItemCatogory.CatogoryName FROM Items JOIN ItemCatogory USING(CatagoryId)
```

Here is a sample code to do this:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

then

```
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
static SqlConnection oc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxx;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;");
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Items.ItemId, ItemCatogory.CatogoryName FROM Items JOIN ItemCatogory USING(CatagoryId)";

oc.Open();
cmd.Connection = oc;
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

GridView1.DataSource = ds;

GridView1.DataBind();

oc.Close();
```

Comment: I can handle db but how to display it with GridView Columns and Cells is the real Issue I am Facing